# Why is there a difference between meat/wine and other restrictions after delayed Tisha B'av

Tags: halacha, minhag, tisha-bav

Since the burning of the Temple began on the ninth day of *Av* and continued on the tenth, therefore it is a good custom not to eat meat on the day after *Tisha B'av* ([*Shulchan Aruch* OC 558:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2919)), at least until midday (*Rema*, ibid.). *Magen Avraham* quoting *Maharshal* adds that other restrictions of the nine days (bathing, laundering, haircuts) also similarly apply till then. When *Tisha B'av* falls on *Shabbos* though and the fast is pushed off to Sunday, a restriction on eating meat and drinking wine still applies for that night (*Rema* OC 558:1), but the other restrictions do not ([*Mishnah Berurah* 558:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=70)). What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83959/breaking-a-fast-with-meat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's little reason to expect them to have the same rule. When the day after the fast of *Tisha Bav* is on 10 Av there is the reason you stated to adopt the restrictive custom: the Temple started burning on 9 Av but continued burning on 10 Av. (Considering that it's actually amazing how lenient we are on 10 Av!)

But that doesn't apply when the day after the fast of *Tisha Bav* is 11 Av. Nothing happened on 11 Av. So everything should be permitted immediately. Nevertheless there is a custom that you cite to avoid meat and wine that night since it is inappropriate or at least can seem inconsiderate to go straight from such intense mourning to such nice food ("מפני אבלות של יום because of the mourning from that day"). Some authorities (Pri Chadash, Birkei Yosef, Kaf HaChayim ad loc) think such a custom is really unnecessary.

The Beit Yosef makes this distinction nicely quoting the Maharil:

> אבל שלא לאכול בשר ולשתות יין ליל מוצאי ט"ב נ"ל דיש ג"כ למנוע כה"ג למי שנוהג שלא לאכול במוצאי ט"ב דאין זה משום חומרא דריב"ז דבו נשרף ההיכל דאפי' מי שאוכל ביום י' בשר יש שנמנעים במוצאי ט"ב משום חומרא דתענית ואבילות של יום ושייך לבין המצרים:‏
>   To not eat meat or drink wine the night after Tisha Bav [when it was postponed to Sunday] it seems to me that you should also avoid it if you avoid it after a [regular] Tisha Bav, for that is not because of [the story of the Temple burning into 10 Av] for even some of those people who eat meat on 10 Av avoid it on the night after Tisha Bav because of the stringency of the fast and the mourning [nature] of the day and it belongs to the [time period of] "in the straights" ([Eikha 1:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3201.htm#3)).

So the stringency you see on 10 Av over 11 Av is not at all unexpected.

But that's still all just about meat and wine and why they'd be more likely to be restricted on 10 Av than 11 Av.

Regarding the extra restrictions of washing/laundering/haircutting, as it happens, we have the original source of imposing them on 10 Av, a practice not mentioned in any of the Rishonim. [Maharshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria) ([responsum #92](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43034&pgnum=132)) thought it logical to be strict to treat 10 Av like the first days of Av which are also customary additions to the laws of the week of Tisha Bav, and luckily for you he directly addresses the case of a postponed fast:

> וא"כ העשירי שהוא בעל מיצרא דט"ב ובו נשרף עיקר הבית כ"ש דלא גרע מהני ימים דהן מר"ח שנהגו בו איסו' אע"פי שאינם בשבוע שחל ט"ב בשלמא לפי דין התלמוד לא קשה מידי דלא אסרו אלא עד התעני' לא גזרו אלא בכח שהציבור יכולין לעמוד בה אבל עכשיו שנהגו וקבלו עליהם איסור אכילת בשר ושתיית יין ורחיצה מה שלא אסרה התלמוד משום צער בעלמא לזכור חורבן הבית ולהעלו' על לבם תוגה א"כ כ"ש בעשירי שהרי מצינו בירושלמי שהחכמים הראשונים היו נוהגין לעשות אותו כט' באב לעניין צום משום דרכי יוחנן שאמר אלמלא הייתי שם הייתי קובע בעשירי ומ"מ נראה היכא שחל ט' באב בשבת ונדחה דשרי אחר התענית הכל שהרי כבר עבר אף העשירי וכן מצאתי להדיא שאפילו במוצא התענית שרי מיד לאכול בשר ולשתות יין אלא שהקארו כתב שב"ל לאסור למי שכבר נהג שלא לאכול בשר במוצאי ט"ב דאין זו משום חומרא דר"יב דבו נשרף ההיכל דאפילו מי שאוכל בשר ביום העשירי נמנע במוצאי ט"ב משום חומרא דתענית ואיבולו של יום ושייך לבין המצרים ע"כ וכתב מילתא בלא טעמא ומ"מ נראו דבריו לפי שמצאתי בספר חסידים שכתבו שעיקר תעני' מעליית' היינו שלא לאכול בשר ולא לשתות יין לא בכניסת התענית ולא במוצאי תענית א"כ כ"ש בתענית זה שכבר היה ראוי להפסיק מבע"י שראוי למנוע מבשר ויין בלילה שלאחר תענית
>   10 Av which is the neighbor of Tisha Bav and on it most of the Temple was burned all the more so that it is no worse than the [those days] from Rosh Chodesh [before] the week of Tisha Bav. In the days of the Talmud they only enacted restrictions [on the week of Tisha Bav because] that's what the community could handle, but now that we accepted [various restrictions even earlier] to remember the destruction of the Temple... all the more so [should they apply] on 10 Av for the Yerushalmi mentions [certain rabbis would [fast on 10 Av too](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43867/extended-fasting-on-10-av)]. Nevertheless when [Tisha Bav is postponed to Sunday] everything is permitted right after the fast... But I saw R. [Yosef] Karo wrote [to forbid meat anyway that night] and he wrote something that is without [good] reason; nevertheless I see his conclusion for I found in Sefer Chasidim that the ideal fast involves not eating meat or drinking wine at the start or end of a fast [which should certainly apply to Tisha Bav].

Not everyone was so excited about his imposing new restrictions on 10 Av (see Beiur Halakha) but you can hopefully see why no one ever extended his stringency to the night of 11 Av.