# Bathing children on Tisha Bav nidche

Tags: tisha-bav

Bathing is normally forbidden on Tisha Bav. May one bathe children on Tisha Bav that is a nidche after chatzos?

Comment: Why do you ask about "Tisha Bav that is a nidche after chatzos" without first asking about anytime on an ordinary Tisha B'av?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What halachos are different this year on the fast of Tisha B'av (Sunday)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94094/what-halachos-are-different-this-year-on-the-fast-of-tisha-bav-sunday)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the nidcheh:

> When Tisha B'Av is a nidcheh, all restrictions are permitted immediately with the conclusion of the fast **on Sunday night** [including bathing, shaving, music, etc...], with the exception of consuming wine[other than for Havdala] and meat, which become permitted at daybreak of Monday morning.
>
> ***Source:*** http://www.shaaray-tefilah.org/weekly/halachos.pdf

Regarding bathing:

> **1.** All bathing for *pleasure* is prohibited even in cold water including the hands, face and feet.
>
> **2.** Ritual washing upon waking, after using the bathroom, touching covered parts of the body or before praying is permitted, but only up to the knuckles.
>
> **3.** One may wash dirty or sullied portions of the body (including cleaning the eyes of glutinous material), and if necessary may use soap or warm water to remove the dirt or odor.
>
> **4.** Washing for cooking or for medical reasons is permitted.
>
> **5.** A woman may not immerse on Tisha B'Av since relations are prohibited. Washing to commence the clean days is permitted.
>
> **Source:** https://ohr.edu/1098

Comment: The question was regarding bathing children, not bathing oneself. This doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between adults and children regarding bathing on Tish B'av.

Comment: That should be your answer, but you don’t include that at all. An answer that actually demonstrates that there’s no difference between adults and children would be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Rabbi Shimon Eider in A Summary Of Halachos Of The Three Weeks on page 32 says that bathing is not permitted until Sunday evening when the tenth of Av falls on a Sunday. He does not differentiate between adults and children.

Comment: Sunday evening... So, after Tishah B’Av, right? The OP is asking regarding Tishah B’Av itself, just after Chatzos. This doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: No, it answers that it is permitted in the evening. I don’t see the word “first” anywhere in this post.