# Source that the customs in regards to the night after Tisha B'av apply on a year when the fast is pushed off

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tisha-bav

There is a custom to keep the restrictions of the "[nine days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/nine-days/info)" throughout the night after the ninth of *Av* (until midday on the tenth). When *Tisha B'av* falls out on *Shabbat*, which causes the fast to be postponed to the tenth, the prohibitions on wine and meat remain in force for that night (only), but (as mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17884/9643)) the other prohibitions do not apply immediately following the fast.

However, the [*Kinnot* that I used this year](http://shaylamora.com/product.php?prod_id=269) states that *all* the restrictions apply on this night.

[image: Kinnot page]

Is there any source for this view? If so, what is their reasoning?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94061/9643

Comment: [Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17883/15571), and practically duplicate

Comment: We were told meat wine and music were forbidden at night.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the customs in regards to \*Yud Av\* apply to \*Yud-Aleph Av\* on a year when the fast is pushed off?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/do-the-customs-in-regards-to-yud-av-apply-to-yud-aleph-av-on-a-year-when-the)

Comment: @Alex I’m not convinced. One refers to Motzaei Tishah B’Av, and the other refers to the following morning.

Comment: @DonielF Even though the title here mentions "night", the first sentence mentions "until midday". Also, even if this question was specifically asking about the night, I might be inclined to think that it's still בעצם the same question. For example (not necessarily exactly the same), if one question asked about eating meat on Tuesday in the Nine Days and one question asked about eating meat on Wednesday in the Nine Days, they are both really asking about eating meat in the Nine Days.

Comment: @Alex Sure, but there’s already a precedent for the practices to differ. For instance, meat and wine were forbidden last night, but not today; one could very easily ask if this extends to anything else.

Comment: @DonielF But that should still be subsumed under the other general question. If different things have different statuses, that would be addressed by the broader question (as it indeed is in Double AA's answer.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure why it's a dupe. That question is asking "do they apply?". My question is "what is the source for X that says they do apply?"

Comment: @Ploni I would think that sources are included in "do they apply". If people answered the other question with mere assertions and no sources, the answers would most likely get downvoted. (Of course, I'm not saying this definitively; I'm just one user with one vote, and the community is certainly entitled to disagree with me.)