Why is there a custom to say "Kiddush Levana" (Moon Blessing) on Motsaei Tisha Be'av?
Why do some have the custom to say Kiddush (Birkat) Levana on Motsaei Tisha Ba'Av and not on the Shabbat after it (or before it)? After all, it is customary to say Kiddush Levana on Motsaei Shabbat is said out of joy and in nice clothes. And we don't wear nice clothes on Tisha Be'Av? And if the temple is not built, then there is no joy either? And besides, the people are hungry after the fast. If so, why did they use to say precisely on Motsaei Tisha Be'Av?

Why not say kiddush levanah on the motzaei shabbat before tish'ah be-av?
Rema Orach Chaim 426:2 (quoting Maharil) writes that one does not recite kiddush levanah before tishah be-av. Mishnah Berurah 8 explains that this is because before tish'ah be-av one is in the midst of mourning.
(However, it is worth noting the custom recorded in Aruch HaShulchan 551:22 to ignore this Maharil and rather to recite kiddush levanah before tish'ah be-av -- as we don't want to delay a mitzvah, and out of concern for subsequent cloudy nights. That was also the practice of the Vilna Gaon (Maaseh Rav 159).)
OK. So why not say it on the motzaei shabbat after tish'ah be-av?
Kiddush levanah can only be said until the moon becomes full (approximately on the fifteenth of the month; see Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 426:3.) Thus when the ninth of Av falls on shabbat or Sunday, one cannot wait until the following motzaei shabbat (the night of 16th or 17th of Av) as it is very likely to be too late.
Even when tish'ah be'av falls on Tuesday, one would not want to wait until motzaei shabbat (the night of the 14th of Av) in case there are a few cloudy nights and he ends up missing the opportunity. (See Rema Orach Chaim 426:2, quoting the Terumat HaDeshen, that in any month one does not wait to say kiddush levanah on motzaei shabbat past the tenth of the month.)
When tish'ah be-av falls on Thursday, Rema in Darchei Moshe (quoted in Mishnah Berurah 10) indeed rules that one waits to say kiddush levanah on the following motzaei shabbat (the night of the twelfth of Av), notwithstanding the general rule of not waiting past the tenth quoted in the previous paragraph.
So kiddush levanah in Av is generally not going to be done on motzaei shabbat. But why do it on motzaei tish'ah be-av?
This is a great question. Rema Orach Chaim 426:2 specifically says not to recite kiddush levanah on motzaei tish'ah be'av, and instead do it on a subsequent night, although not (in general) waiting for motzaei shabbat. Levush ibid. :4 writes such as well. Mishnah Berurah 10 explains (as you note in your question) that motzaei tish'ah be'av is not a time of joy. (Presumably, Rema would also instruct you to put on nice clothes when you recite kiddush levanah on a weeknight following motzaei tish'ah be-av, as he rules in general regarding reciting kiddush levanah on a weeknight (462:2).)
However, as you observe, many people do not follow this ruling of Rema, and do recite kiddush levanah on motzaei tish'ah be'av.
Mishnah Berurah 11 quotes "the acharonim" as permitting this practice, but notes the incongruity of reciting kiddush levanah while still fasting and not wearing shoes. He therefore writes that one should eat something and put on one's shoes before reciting kiddush levanah on motzaei tish'ah be'av. (In Sha'ar HaTziyun 9, he points out that if waiting to eat will cause one to miss reciting kiddush levanah with the community, it is better to recite it with them before eating, due to the principle of berov am hadrat melech.)
If we rule against the Rema, then kiddush levanah in Av can be done on motzaei tish'ah be-av. Is there a specific reason to do so, rather than waiting until a later night?
Baer Heitev to Orach Chaim 551:8 notes the Arizal's directive to specifically recite kiddush levanah on motzaei tisha'ah be-av, as it is the time of Mashiach's birth, which ties in thematically with the rebirth of the moon.
On a more practical level, we pointed out that one is not supposed to wait past the tenth of the month to recite kiddush levanah, out of concern for cloudy nights. That being the case, once we rule that it is permitted to recite kiddush levanah on motzaei tisha'ah be-av (the tenth of Av), my assumption is that one should specifically do so, to minimize the chances of missing it (as well as the general principle of doing mitzvot as speedily as possible). See Kenesset HaGedolah, Orach Chaim 426 who invokes the worry about cloudy nights as a reason to not push off reciting kiddush levanah from motzaei tish'ah be-av.
Further, in many communities, I imagine that arvit on motzaei tish'ah be-av attracts larger crowds than a regular weeknight arvit. Therefore, it makes sense to me for those communities to specifically recite kiddush levanah then, to increase the chances of more members of the community reciting it that month.

The Ari was seemingly living before Maharshal's chumra caught on https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94070/759 so nowadays when 10 Av is part of the "9 days" you have the first Rama to deal with on 10 Av as well. (Put a different way, if you're willing to say KL on 10 Av, you're better off saying it on 4 Av when the mourning is arguably weaker.)

The clouds thing is an estimate for Poland of little relevance to the summertime in Israel. And, if we want to forget about these customs in favor of encouraging people to say it (reasonable enough), Motzash of 9 days is certainly a bigger crowd than 10 Av.

When 9 Av is shabbat, then 10 Av is the fast. But we shouldn't push off on 10 Av and it's already Sat night? (It's probably worth noting at the top that everyone agrees it's technically mutar all month, it's just a question of doing at a better time. If so Terumat Hadeshen should apply.)

OK, but Rema himself says to push off from 10th to 11th Av every year, (and 12th when 9 Av is Thurs) notwithstanding Terumat Hadeshen. So  it's seemingly just a question of balancing priorities - how much better is it to wait until the fast/mourning recedes vs chance of missing KL? Plus you are not wearing shoes or nice clothes on Sat night 10 Av.

Yes I agree just in your second to last point you invoke clouds when apparently most assume these sorts of customs trump clouds (even for the Ari, cf Yom Kippur). It's important general framing as well lest someone think there's any real risk involved in the different (and often relatively late) customs.

Got it. Note Kenesset HaGedolah who does invoke the clouds issue in this context (although it's not clear to me whether he is working within the framework of the Maharil's not saying KL during the 9 days) https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14597&st=&pgnum=118

Nice source. I agree, it seems like he's not within the rama, because he makes it sound like it was a one time event where he ended up needing to do it. It also seems obvious to me the Rama is referring to Bahab, I guess he wasn't familiar with bahab out in Turkey?

Why do you say (in your first comment) that mourning on 4 Av is arguably weaker than 10 Av? Aren't the mourning customs of 4th Av (even assuming we're talking before shavua shechal bo) older than those of 10th Av?

Extended supererogatory mourning on 10 Av dates back to the Yerushalmi. See Maharshal linked above who argues כל שכן from 4 Av to 10 Av. (4 Av is always before Shavua Shechal Bo since we hold in a nidche year there is no ShShB.)

DM quotes "מהרי"ל לא היה מקדש הלבנה במ"ש של חזון ישעיה אך המתין עד מ"ש נחמו כי אין מקבלין הלבנה אלא מתוך שמחה" meaning it's a choice of sat nights (probably how they thought about it) and they didn't wear shabbat clothes on chazon. Arguably nowadays when we treat chazon as a normal happy day and are wearing nice clothes at the end, the whole argument doesn't apply. Maharil doesnt say anything explicit about 9 days mourning practices (rama does say "after 9Av" but he also wouldnt let you wear nice clothes any of the 9 days). If its all about clothes breaking your fast doesn't even help for 10Av

I wonder what Maharil would have done in a year when tish'ah be-av fell on shabbat or sunday
