# Wearing clean clothes immediately after Tish'ah beAv

Tags: minhag, nine-days, washing-clothes

[Mishnah Berurah 558:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.558.3?lang=bi) records a custom to continue the restrictions of the 'Nine Days' regarding bathing, haircuts and laundering clothing until midday of the tenth of Av.

Is this list exhaustive? What about other restrictions of the Nine Days which he doesn't mention? I'm thinking particularly about wearing clothes which were laundered before the Nine Days and have not been worn since (which are restricted during the Nine Days as per [Shulchan Aruch 551:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.551.3?lang=bi)).

Comment: Here they include it in the list, although they don't give a reference https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144576/jewish/Tisha-BAv-Order-of-the-Day.htm

Comment: @Kazibácsi Where? I seem them list eating meat, swimming, or laundering clothing, but no explicit discussion of wearing freshly laundered clothing

Comment: "laundering clothing" and "wearing laundered clothing" is the same thing. We're not an issur melakha on shabbos...

Comment: @doubleaa So why does Shulchan Aruch 551:3 have to list both items?

Comment: @JoelK why did the mishna not have to?

Comment: Here's a better source: לדעת רוב האחרונים, בנוסף לאיסור לאכול בשר ולשתות יין, עד חצות גם אין לכבס או ללבוש בגדים מכובסים, ואין להסתפר ואין לשמוע מוזיקה משמחת ואין לרחוץ בחמים. https://ph.yhb.org.il/05-10-19/#_te01ftnref10_25

Comment: @Kazibácsi Yes. That is explicit

Comment: @DoubleAA I hear. Although the MB continues, "כשחל ט"ב ביום ה' שאז יום עשירי הוא ע"ש מותר בכל זה לכבוד שבת". According to you, he ought to point out that only laundering for shabbat is permitted, not laundering for / wearing freshly laundered clothes on Friday morning.

Comment: @Joel He also should point out that laundering your weekday clothes for a meeting next Monday is asur. He clearly thought that people will understand what he meant (or that there's a lo plug lekula)

Comment: @DoubleAA My assumption has always been that there is a lo plug lekula regarding כיבוס להניח on Thursday night / Friday. Whether that also extends to wearing freshly laundered clothes on Friday morning I am less sure about.

Comment: @JoelK I always (when 9av is Thursday) make fun of people who think that / don't clarify in their shul announcements that it's just stuff for shabbat. Willing to be proven wrong if you can

Comment: Listen, everything on 10 Av is a minhag, so if the local minhag is to only observe some of the laundering restrictions, so be it and that's all that's binding in that place. One could always choose [to be stricter than the minimal binding restrictions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43867/759) and Ashrei Chelko. All I'm saying is were this shavua shechal bo midina, this would afaict be the halacha.

Comment: The rules are the same as things forbidden to mourners in shiva. mourners cannot wear freshly cleaned or new clothes, with the exception of undergarments. One way to wear your clothes is to get them a little dirty by for instance dragging them on the floor (doesn't have to get that dirty). The minhag is to keep the restrictions into the 10th since the temple was still burning.  When Tisha BAv is pushed off until after shabbos so celebrating on 10th, the restrictions end when the fast ends

Comment: @DoubleAA https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50289&st=&pgnum=41 (footnote א) (Not that this is the only opinion on the topic by any means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Midwest Agudas Yisroel Council of Synagogue Rabbonim writes [here](https://agudathisrael.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Halachos-of-the-Three-Weeks.pdf), p. 32, that **the restrictions of 10 Av midday extend to wearing freshly laundered clothing**

> The following is a list of the activities that remain forbidden until
> chatzos on the 10th of Av and the possible exceptions
>
> 1. Eating meat and drinking wine (Food cooked with meat is permissible).
> 2. Bathing and showering (Washing parts of the body with warm water is permissible)
> 3. Haircuts and shaving
> 4. Washing clothes (If one will be leaving home on the 10th of Av for an extended trip, he may do laundry right after Tisha B’Av at night)
> 5. Listening to music
> 6. **Wearing freshly laundered clothing**
> 7. Saying the beracha of “She’hechiyanu”